# Merge from one of multiple columns in dataframe based on first match

Tags: r, merge

Suppose I have two dataframes that look like the following:

```
V1 V2 V3  
A  A1 A11  
A  A1 NA   
B  B2 NA    
B  NA NA   
NA NA NA
```

```
geo value
A     5
A1    3
A11   1
B     6
B2    7
B21   9
```

I want to merge the "value" of the second dataframe into the first dataframe, at the finest geo value possible. So, for row one, I want to merge based on column V3, because it has a value present. However, row two only has V2, so instead of merging based on column V3, I want to merge based on V2. The desired output would be the following:

```
V1 V2 V3  Value
A  A1 A11  1
A  A1 NA   3
B  B2 NA   7  
B  NA NA   6
NA NA NA  NA
```

I can perform multiple merges, however this ends up creating multiple redundent "Value.x", "Value.y", etc. columns. Is there a way to merge based on the first matching column, then proceeding to the next matching column if there is an NA value in the previous (finer) column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in Base R:

Which does some matching based on return from `pmax`

```
df1$Value = df2$value[match(do.call(pmax,  c(rev(df1), na.rm = T)), df2$geo)]
```

```
     V1   V2   V3 Value
1    A   A1  A11     1
2    A   A1 <NA>     3
3    B   B2 <NA>     7
4    B <NA> <NA>     6
5 <NA> <NA> <NA>    NA
```

Comment: I had the same `pmax` idea, and this will always work in the specific case of OP's question where V3 is always a longer/additional string that builds on V2 etc. It will however fall over if the 'finer' string is something like `"A011"` which doesn't sort nicely as the `max`imum. Though you could of course still do something in base R like `Reduce(\(x,y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x), rev(d1))` instead (which is similar to dplyr's `coalesce` ).

Comment: yep that is true

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr`'s `coalesce` function works like the same function in SQL, outputting the first non-NA from a list of possible values, which we can specify in terms of preference. We can join based on that.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(finest = coalesce(V3, V2, V1)) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("finest" = "geo"))
```

Result

```
    V1   V2   V3 finest value
1    A   A1  A11    A11     1
2    A   A1 <NA>     A1     3
3    B   B2 <NA>     B2     7
4    B <NA> <NA>      B     6
5 <NA> <NA> <NA>   <NA>    NA
```